# Some JS and CSS assets not loading on Heroku, although loading locally

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

Locally, my node.js with express app works as expected. When I push to Heroku, the app is able to load some stylesheets and javascripts, but not others. Here is the relevant snippet from app.js:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Here are the assets that I'm loading from my jade templates:

```
link(href='/stylesheets/style.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='/lib/bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='/lib/bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css', rel='stylesheet')
script(src='/lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js')
script(src='/lib/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js')
```

Everything works locally, but when I push to Heroku, the `style.css` file and the jquery file are loaded fine. The bootstrap files return a 404.

I'm baffled why this would work locally but would break, and in parts, on Heroku.

Comment: Did you check in your bootstrap files?

Comment: I'm discovering things about git submodules. I copied bootstrap from a git repo and then attempted to removed the .git and .gitconfig from boostrap since I don't care about making it an official submodule. I just wanted the files. The only way I got it to work and be able to commit all of the files was by deleting .git and .gitconfig first, and then copy in the files to the repo.

Comment: It might be a good option to use CDN. There's one for bootstrap http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ and for jquery http://jquery.com/download/ at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that the files are really present
2. Check if your static files are being served by node or the web server e.g. nginx.  It is possible the web server is misconfigured to serve static files and is not looking in /lib/bootstrap/